# How to use tar to archive files from different directories without directory structure

Tags: linux, tar

I have several hundred to thousand files in different subdirectories which all reside in one parent directory, e.g.

```
/home/dir1/file1
/home/dir2/file2
/home/dir3/file3
...
/home/dir10000/file10000
```

How can I use tar so my tar archive looks like this?

```
file1
file2
file3
```

I can ensure that the file names are unique. I do not want to include the original directory structure.

Thanks for you help folks!

Answer (score 6):

The one way to solve this without `cat`ing or `|`ing to other programs:

```
tar --transform 's,.*/,,g' -cvf mytarfile.tar /path/to/parent_dir

# --transform accepts a regular expression similar to sed.
#   I used "," as a delimiter so I don't have to escape "/"
#   This will replace anything up to the final "/" with ""
#   /path/to/parent_dir/sub1/sub2/subsubsub/file.txt -> file.txt
#   /path/to/parent_dir/file2.txt -> file2.txt
```

Unlike Aaron Okano implies, there is no need to pipe to `xargs` if you have a long list of files *within a single / few parent directories* that you can specify on the command line.

Answer (score 3):

GNU tar will take a transform option, which is just a sed expression that transforms the file name in the archive. You will also probably want to pipe to xargs if your list of files is very large.

```
cat filelist | xargs tar -rvf archive.tar --transform='s|.*/||g'
```

Keep in mind that this is appending to a tar archive (it will create one if it does not exist yet) so you will want to delete the archive if it already exists before running that command.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution might be to use the ordinary `tar` command (spitting on its *stdout*) and then to pipe the archive into [tardy](http://tardy.sourceforge.net/), probably with its  `-No_Directories` option, i.e.

```
 tar cf - /home/dir?/ | tardy -No-Directories > yourbig.tar
```

<sup>However, I am not sure it is a good idea. Having a tar ball which is extracting into hundred of thousands of files in the same directory is not a good idea (some filesystems behave badly with that).</sup>

Answer (score -3):

Open the command line and type

```
tar -cvf NAME.tar /home/dir1/file1 /home/dir1/file2 /home/dir1/file3
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I have several 100-10000 files where I do not know the name. Any other idea where I just can use the /home directory?

Comment: This does not answer's the OP concern of avoiding the directory structure in the tarball

Comment: Basically this will still create the folder structure in the tar/tgz